# Grab items moved into listBox onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm using the javascript from this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/RbLVQ/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=RbLVQ

A user can select 1 or more items from the first listBox and move them over to a second listBox.

I added a button which should grab the items in the second listBox, but cannot grab the items unless they are "selected".  Basically, they need to be highlighted to be identified as selected.

The javascript from the fiddle (above) has not changed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnRight').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
        alert("Nothing to move.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#btnLeft').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
        alert("Nothing to move.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

My button click looks like this:

```
$('#massSubmit').on('click', function()
{
  var lstBox2 = $('#lstBox2').val();

  console.log('this is listbox ' + lstBox2);
});
```

Per the button click, unless the items in the second listBox are selected, they will not appear in the console.

How can I automatically select the items in the second listBox on the onClick event?

Comment: create two more buttons `<<` and '>>', to move the all items from one list to other. take all the elements using  https://jsfiddle.net/m8aLw4es/

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough, which is why I was downvoted.  But I have no problem getting the items from one box to the other.  What I need to do is on the button click (which would be a submit button), I need to grab all of the values that were moved into the second list box and display them on the screen.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you update the js fiddle with `#massSubmit` button.

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/HoodCoderMan/vbafy3qs/2/  Be sure to open the console.  If you don't select an item in the second checkbox, the console will show a null value.  But if you select an item in the second checkbox, you'll see the selection.  I need to automatically select all items in the second checkbox.

Comment: check this for the solution, https://jsfiddle.net/rcefxq2y/

Comment: Your solution is what worked.  Not sure if you want to add an answer here, but if you do, I will accept it.  Thank you, sir.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution

html

```
 <table style='width:370px;'>
    <tr>
        <td style='width:160px;'>
            <b>Group 1:</b><br/>
           <select multiple="multiple" id='lstBox1'>
              <option value="ajax">Ajax</option>
              <option value="jquery">jQuery</option>
              <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
              <option value="mootool">MooTools</option>
              <option value="prototype">Prototype</option>
              <option value="dojo">Dojo</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td style='width:50px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;'>
        <input type='button' id='btnRight' value ='  >  '/>
        <br/><input type='button' id='btnLeft' value ='  <  '/>
        <br/><input type='button' id='btnAllLeft' value ='  <<  '/>
        <br/><input type='button' id='btnAllRight' value ='  >> '/>
    </td>
    <td style='width:160px;'>
        <b>Group 2: </b><br/>
        <select multiple="multiple" id='lstBox2'>
          <option value="asp">ASP.NET</option>
          <option value="c#">C#</option>
          <option value="vb">VB.NET</option>
          <option value="java">Java</option>
          <option value="php">PHP</option>
          <option value="python">Python</option>  
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" id="massSubmit" name="massSubmit">Save</button>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnRight').click(function(e) {
        var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
        if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
        $(selectedOpts).remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#btnLeft').click(function(e) {
        var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
        if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
        $(selectedOpts).remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

     $('#btnAllLeft').click(function(e) {
        var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option');
        if (selectedOpts.length === 0) {
           e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#lstBox1').append(selectedOpts);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#btnAllRight').click(function(e) {
        var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option');
        if (selectedOpts.length === 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#lstBox2').append(selectedOpts);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

$('#massSubmit').on('click', function()
{
 var lstBox2 = $('#lstBox2').val();
 if(!lstBox2) {
   var value = "";
   $('#lstBox2 option').each((index,element) => {
      value += $(element).attr('value') + ",";
   });
   lstBox2 = value;
   console.log("value-->"+value);
 } 
 console.log('this is listbox ' + lstBox2);

});
```

css

```
  body
{
    padding:10px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:8pt;
}

select
{
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:8pt;
    width : 150px;
    height:100px;
}
input
{
    text-align: center;
    v-align: middle;
}
```